# How to test an exception in an Observable?

Tags: jestjs, mocking, observable, nestjs

I have httpService that is an Observable, but just before returning, I'm turning it into a Promise with "lastValueFrom"

```
 async getRandomRecipes(): Promise<BasicRecipe> {
    const res = this.httpService
      .get<ClientBasicRecipe>(url)
      .pipe(
        map((response) => {
          return response.data;
        }),
        catchError((err) => throwError(() => new NotFoundException())), // Trying to test this exception
      )
      .pipe<BasicRecipe>(map((data) => this.getBasicRecipe(data)));

    return lastValueFrom(res);
  }
```

I want to test this exception with jest, but not sure how to do it. I know to use jest.spyOn on HttpService, but since it's an Observable; I don't know how to mock it properly.

This is what I have so far:

```
   it("throw NotFoundException when there are no recipes", async ()=>{
      jest
      .spyOn(HttpService.prototype, 'get')
      .mockImplementationOnce(() => throw new NotFoundException);
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

While working with `Observables` you need to understand that you can't rely on `async/await` to consider your test done. So, you can use the `done` parameter to handle that for you.

In your example, you will need to return an `Observable` within the mock implementation of the `get` function and, within that `Observable` you should throw an error.

Comment: the reason I'm converting this into a Promise is because another service is using this method and that returns a promise. So should I return an Observable in this getRandomRecipes method and then convert it to a Promise in that other method?

Comment: Well, I don't think you're going to be able to convert it to a promise. At least I never saw a successful test implementation using observables with promises. I suggest not using it and converting the rest of your test to work with callbacks